# CDO.Message .Send causes script execution timeout

Tags: email, asp-classic, smtp

I have the following code:

```
Set myMailanon = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
myMailanon.MimeFormatted = True

Set myConfanon = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
Set objBPanon = myMailanon.AddRelatedBodyPart("http://www.foo.bar/img/logo1.jpg", "http://www.foo.bar/img/logo1.jpg", CdoReferenceTypeName)
objBPanon.Fields.Item("urn:schemas:mailheader:Content-ID") = "<http://www.foo.bar/img/logo1.jpg>" 
objBPanon.Fields.Update 
ConfURLanon = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"

with myConfanon        
  .Fields.Item(ConfURLanon & "sendusing") = 2        
  .Fields.Item(ConfURLanon & "smtpserver") = "smtp.foo.bar"        
  .Fields.Item(ConfURLanon & "smtpserverport") = 25     
  .Fields.Item(ConfURLanon & "smtpusessl") = false
  .Fields.Item(ConfURLanon & "smtpauthenticate") = 1
  .Fields.Item(ConfURLanon & "sendusername") = "foo@bar.com"
  .Fields.Item(ConfURLanon & "sendpassword") = "foobarpass"
  .Fields.Update
end with

with myMailanon
  .Subject='Foo!! Bar!!'
  .From='Foo!! Bar!! <foo@bar.com>'      
  .To='foo@bar.com,bar@foo.com'      
  txt="This is foo... bar... text... SPARTAAAAAAAAA"
  .HTMLBody = txt
  Set .Configuration = myConfanon   
  On Error Resume Next 
  .Send      
end with
```

Problem is that this code, run 100 times, will work 30 and fail 70. Randomly.
And by "fail" I mean that it will cause Script execution timeout.

After commenting line by line, I got to the conclusion that the error comes from ".Send".
But why? Any ideas?

Regards

Comment: Could be that one of the external assets isn't loading. Like http://www.foo.bar/img/logo1.jpg, or the SMTP server is busy or unavailable.

Comment: I haven't tought about the assets loading, I'll make sure to comment all those in my code. About the SMTP being buse, what do you mean? Like CDO trying to connect with the SMTP and timing out? If so, that should be fixed with connectiontimeout, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't anything wrong with code (athough `CdoReferenceTypeName` looks a little suspect but that could be just poor variable naming).  It could just be that the SMTP server is busy and is therefore taking a while to process the send.

You could check the Script Time-out value specified for the ASP feature in IIS manager.  By default it should be 90 seconds but perhaps its been set to a low value for some reason.

You can increase the amount of time you script has by specifying it in your code.

```
Server.ScriptTimeout = 300
```

Which would give your script a 5 minutes.  This may well be masking some set up problem between your web server and SMTP server but it may increase the success rate.  OTH you may get the same results but the 70% failures take longer to occur.

Whatever the cause I don't think its your code.

Comment: After moving the entire website, changing webserver, etc... I found that the problem is that CDO.Message isn't able to connect to *any* server. The exact code error is: The transport failed to connect to the server. ( error '80040213' ). I tried with a few accounts, some of them in my email server, some of them outside it (I even tried with a gmail account), none of them work. It's just like CDO.Message is refusing to connect to any server. Also, that was happening with both my server (the web was hosted on my server) and on 1and1 server. Any ideas?